# Get images to display in Rails with Has Many/Belongs To Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

I'm trying to get images to display on this recipes index page. At this point I have a recipes model, a user model, and an images model. I have the images model belonging to the recipes model, and the recipes model has many images. The user model has many images through the recipes model.

The error I'm getting from the terminal is undefined method 'url' from nilClass. Url is a defined field on my images table. If I run recipe.images in the index I do get broken image links to appear on the page. It's the .url that isn't working.

Here are my models

First up is image

```
  class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :recipe
  end
```

This is user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :recipes

  has_many :images, through: :recipes

end
```

This is recipes

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :images

end
```

This is the index view page set up through the recipes controller

```
<h1>Recipes</h1>

<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>
  <h2><%= recipe.name %></h2>
  <a href="/recipes/<%= recipe.id %>"> <img src="<%= recipe.images.first.url %>" alt="<%= recipe.name %>"></a>
  <p>Cooktime:<%= recipe.cooktime %>
  Serves:<%= recipe.amount %></p>
  <p>Description:<%= recipe.description %></p>

<% end %>
```

And finally here is a look at the recipes controller

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @recipes = Recipe.all

  end

  def new

    @recipe = Recipe.new

  end

  def create

    @recipe = Recipe.create({
      name: params[:name],
      description: params[:description],
      ingredients: params[:ingredients],
      directions: params[:directions],
      amount: params[:amount],
      cooktime: params[:cooktime],
      favorite: params[:favorite],
      user_id: params[:user_id],
      })
    Image.create({
      url: params[:image],
      recipe_id: @recipe.id
      })

    render :show

  end

  def show

    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

  end

  def edit

    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

  end

  def update

    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])

    @recipe.update({
      name: params[:name],
      description: params[:description],
      ingredients: params[:ingredients],
      directions: params[:directions],
      amount: params[:amount],
      cooktime: params[:cooktime],
      favorite: params[:favorite],
      user_id: params[:user_id]
      })

    render :show

  end

  def destroy

    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @recipe.destroy

    redirect_to "/recipes"

  end

end
```

Comment: your recipe doesn't have any images.  The undefined method .url on nil class tell you that recipe.images.first is nil.  Your are accessing the attribute correctly but the data just isn't there.

Comment: There are images in images table in the url fields.  I've also been trying to add this method to the recipes model, and I'm still getting this same error.                                                                                           def first_image_display
    if images.first.url
      images.first.url
    else
      Image.first.url
    end
  end

Comment: There may be images in the images table but there are none associated with that recipe